# Performance issues while converting from string to float in a 6M documents collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a >6M documents collection in mongodb. And one of it's fields (field1 and field2 in the example below) are string values (type 2 in mongodb).

My problem is that I want to parse them into float values (all the values are  *parseFloat-able*). I found this snippet in SO. But it doesn't seems to be a great solution to deal with a 6M document collection.

```
db.collection.find({field1: {$type:1}}).forEach(function(data) {
    db.collection.update(
         {_id:data._id},
         {$set:{
              field1: parseFloat(data.field1),
              field2: parseFloat(data.field2)}
          }
    )
})
```

Is there any way I can convert my two fields **without slowing down the server** ?

Using db.collection.getIndexes() and db.collection.getIndexKeys() says that my two fields are indexed.

Comment: You're trying to do a 6M update. No matter if you do this in cycle or will use any fancy update construction, it's still 6M update in one go. Write a migration procedure that will take a range of values at a time and do an update.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do something like skip(x).limit(y) ? and iterate over it?

Comment: Yes, but keep a note that skip&limit can be inaccurate if you'll keep adding documents, and sorting at the end of the list can be very resource expensive. You can add new indexed flag like "processed" to each document and at the end remove it in one go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to prevent server slowdown then I would introduce a sleep on the client end between updates. You can adjust the timeout depending on how much load you want to reduce and your patience for the updates to complete. To force a sleep call "sleep(ms)" in the mongo shell where "ms" is the number of milliseconds you would like to sleep for.

Comment: how much milliseconds do you suggest to avoid slowing down the server?

Comment: I wanted to test it, and it seems that there's neither *setTimeout* nor *setInterval* in the mongo shell

Comment: Well the sleep function is simply called *sleep*

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my answer above for proper sleep methedology. As for # of milliseconds there is no hard rule. It is really a tradeoff of load reduction versus run-time of this operation. My suggestion would to be to formulate a sleep value based on the length of time you are willing to wait for this operation to complete. Once you have it run a test on a subset of documents to see whether the load produced is acceptable to you.

Comment: Well, I used a cursor, and made the script sleep for 25 ms for each iteration (I may lower or higher this number as needed). Seems to be fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using forEach and executing one update command per document, have you tried setting the [4th argument of update](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29) to true so that you can perform a multi-document update?

Comment: I need to _get_ the field value, _then_ parseFloat it. Hence, every document has a different value (obviously).